# input value issues in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I hav a google published csv sheet. I created a html table and want to display csv values from published csv sheet into all input fields inside html table.

due to a unspecified reason this question has been moved.

Comment: `xmlhttp.responseText.trim();` so you need to split it up.....

Comment: @epascarello I don't' know how to do it. Can you please post your code?

Comment: You can use split() function.  example :  let splitedResult = xmlhttp.responseText.split(" ");  console.log(splitedResult[0].trim(), splitedResult[1].trim()). You can assign the values to element.value = splitedResult[0].trim(); element1.value = splitedResult[1].trim() ......

Comment: @Syam not working. Can you please test and post your code?

Comment: @planpoint can you check this link https://jsfiddle.net/SyamKumarD/xa49vspy/22/

Comment: Please post your answer @Syam instead so OP and other users can confirm and vote your answer.

Comment: Sure @ASyntuBU , i will add it

Comment: @Styam last 2 cell is not working. Checked your js. So the code is still useless. Would you please double check and test? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because there is no space in between the last 2-3 values planpoint. You should be able to do it if you try to understand it a bit, not be condescending to the person who just extended his/her hand to help you. @Syam, better split by any whitespace in your answer then trim the resulting string

Comment: You could also introduce a loop since input name has a pattern @Syam. Code above seems so tedious

Comment: @planpoint only thing you need to do in the below solution is just replace split(" ") with split("\r") that will resolve your issue. I have updated the latest fiddle link in the answer. hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Split()** function https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
let splitedResult = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\r");
```

You can assign the values to

```
element.value = splitedResult[0].trim();
element1.value = splitedResult[1].trim();
```

Check out this link for the implementation https://jsfiddle.net/SyamKumarD/xa49vspy/29/

I would suggest you to provide a iterable id to your table elements, so you don't need to hardcode the index to your split result and you can iterate through the element and assign the split value dynamically.

Comment: Last couple of values were not separated by space. You might need to split by whitespace or better yet, a new line to be specific instead and then trim. Aside from that, you should be golden.

Comment: @Syam I really don't know how to fix last 2 cells or how to add white spaces. Because these values are inside of google published csv file. Even still I have no idea. Thank you for your answer. But if you can properly fix the code, I will accept ur answer. Because I'm still unable to fix the code.

Comment: @planpoint, answer's been updated. use \r instead.